# sort the numbers A to Z and change the least number to the word "Win"

Tags: excel

It has been almost 1 day I am struggling with this. Please see the picture where I want to sort the list according to the number in the row "C". But the key point is that there is some spacing there. I tried the standard sort function but it did not help because it mixes up all the lines and trims the spaces also. 
[image]

The aim here is: I need to take the least number from there and replace all least numbers for each table (single worksheet like in the picture) to the word "Win". Is it possible to do ? Any helps , would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what the final outcome should like like? By "Least number" do you mean the minimal value in the whole of col C or the min in each sub-table? Do you really need to "replace" values, or is it acceptable to put the adjusted new value into col D?

Comment: I have attached new picture to show what is the final scene I want to like to see.. Eliminate all other numbers except smallest number and keep appropriate ID. We dont need even change anything just eliminate all numbers in all sub-tables except smallest number and make the table like in the picture. thanks. (check the screenshot in first post).

Comment: it is even ok if you add the value in the new columnd (D). so that I will be able to figure out then

Comment: Are there always 6 entries in each table?

Comment: there are more than 6 , hundreds of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the label `Winner` was in cell D1 and `Winning value` in E1.

Add these formulae:
E2 = `Min(C2:C7)`
D2 = `index(b2:b7,match(E2,c2:c7,0))`

Copy those two cells and paste at the top of each subsequent table, i.e. into D11:E11, D19:E19 etc